# Conclude almost sure convergence from the expectation

Tags: probability-theory, martingales

It is shown that the following martingale
\begin{equation}
X_n = \prod _{i=1}^n e^{Y_i - \frac{1}{2}}
\end{equation}
where $Y_i$ has a standard normal distribution, converges almost surely.

To this end, notice that
$$
E(|X_n|) = E(X_n) = e^{-n / 2}E(e^{Y_i})^n = 1.
$$
so $sup_n E(|X_n|) = 1$ and almost sure convergence follows.

How can we conclude almost sure convergence by noting that $sup_n E(|X_n|) = 1$?

Comment: Do you know the martingale convergence theorem?

Comment: I wasn't aware of that theorem. I just looked it up, it answers my question. Thank you! Using the theorem, can we find which $X$ it converges to?

Comment: The martingale convergence theorem itself won't tell you the limit.  For this martingale, you can use Kakutani's product martingales theorem to show that the almost sure limit is $0$.

Comment: $\log X_n$ is the sum of i.i.d random variables, to which you could apply the Law of Large Numbers.